# Axios Cors error in VueJs ( using Quasar framework ) on Laravel API

Tags: laravel, vue.js, quasar

I am using this framework https://quasar.dev/ for my Front-End and Laravel for my API Back-End. I am trying to login using axios POST but I keep getting a CORS error:

On my Front-End I'm running npm run dev and get the http://localhost:8080 local server. As for the Laravel API I am using a xampp webserver that's on http://localhost but on default port I assume.

**The error:**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/vuecommerce-api/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

**Axios call:**

```
const Store = new Vuex.Store({
modules: {
  // example
},

actions: {
  async retrieveToken (context, credentials) {
    var url = 'http://localhost/vuecommerce-api/api/login'
    var post = {
      username: credentials.username,
      password: credentials.password
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        withCredentials: true,
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        data: post
      })
        .then(response => {
          const token = response.data.access_token

          localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)
          context.commit('retrieveToken', token)
          resolve(response)
          // console.log(response);
          // context.commit('addTodo', response.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('aici error')
          console.log(error)
          reject(error)
        })
    })
    ...
```

> Important mention, for the login I am using Laravel Passport via this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRhkhSzyApc&t=300s

**Weird thing:**

I have created a Cors middleware for my Laravel Back-End and added it to the endpoints:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Method', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
            ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
}
```

> On another page I make a Axios GET request to another endpoint for getting the products, and that one works.

**If this helps with anything:**

```
/**
 * POST Login
 * 
 * @var \Illuminate\Http\Request
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
 */
public function login (Request $request) {
    print response()->header('')
    exit('request');

    $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $login_endpoint = config('services.passport.login_endpoint');
    $post = [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
                    'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
                    'username' => $request->username,
                    'password' => $request->password,
                ]
            ];

    // Request
    print response()->json($request->all());
    exit('request');

    // Oauth
    // print response()->json($post);
    // exit('request');

    try {
        $response = $http->post($login_endpoint, [
            $post
        ]);

        print response()->json($response);
        exit('gata');

        return $response->getBody();
    }
    catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        // Error
        // print response()->json($e->getMessage());
        // exit('error');
        if($e->getCode() == 400) {
            return response()->json('Invalid Request. Please enter a username or password.', $e->getCode());
        }
        elseif($e->getCode() == 401) {
            return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again.', $e->getCode());
        }
    }
}
```

It never reaches the php function because of CORS, so none of my prints and exists work.

Comment: The error refers to the preflight OPTIONS request. Are you clear what that means? There are several problems with this code. e.g. `*` wildcards are not supported if you're using `withCredentials`. You're setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as a request header when it should be a response header. I don't think axios has settings called `credentials` or `mode`. To debug CORS problems you should keep a very close eye on the requests and headers in the Network tab of the browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

in my case change 'paths' => ['api/*'], to 'paths' => ['*'], and work perfect.